# Webpack 4 - Splitchunks

Tags: javascript, webpack-4, webpack-splitchunks, splitchunksplugin

I have set chunks : 'all' in split chunks. But my js is compiled but it not rendering. Where should I  include the chunk file. Can it be achieved without HTMLWebpackPlugin ?

```
optimization: {
            splitChunks: {
                cacheGroups: {
                    vendors: {
                        chunks: 'all',
                        test: /\/node_modules\//,
                        enforce: true,
                    }

                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the created chunk file as chunkFilename.

```
output: {
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
```